# Create invoices and payments then link them by code in Odoo module

Tags: odoo, odoo-13

I'm using Odoo 13, I created model called **my_module.invoice**, after using this model I need to register some payments, so I created another model called **my_module.payment**, the have a one to many relation and they work ok. After the payments complete their related invoice, I need to take the values of my module's invoice and payments and create the same scenario in Odoo using **account.move** and **account.payment**.
I was able to convert my_module.invoice into account.move and my_module.payment into account.payment but a can't link them.

This is the code for converting my model into Odoo's:

```py
# "record" is my_module.invoce model and "ni" is Odoo's account.move model
# Here I convert my invoice model into Odoo's model
new_invoice = record.env['account.move']
ni = new_invoice.create({
    'partner_id': record.client,
    'invoice_date': record.invoice_date,
    'type': 'out_invoice',
    'state': 'draft',
    'invoice_line_ids': [(0, 0, {'product_id': record.product_id,
                                    'account_id': record.account_id,
                                    'name': record.product_name,
                                    'quantity': 1,
                                    'price_unit': record.total_to_pay
                                    }
                            )],
})
```

Then if the account.move is created then, the module creates the account.payment:

```py
# If ni (account.move) is true, it means the invoice has been created, so lets create the account.payment
if ni:
    new_payment = self.env['account.payment']
    np = new_payment.create({
        'payment_type': 'inbound',
        'has_invoices': True,
        'payment_method_id': 1,
        'partner_type': 'customer',
        'partner_id': some_client,
        'amount': my_module.payment.amount,
        'payment_date': my_module.payment.create_date,
        'journal_id': my_module.payment.journal_id.id,
        'communication': ni,
    })
    np.post()
```

To this point, things work as expected, but I don't know how to assign the newly created account.payment to the newly created account.move

Has anyone been through this scenario or know how to link them?

Note: The reason I'm creating different models to converting them into the Odoo's models is because there is some logic and conditions before using the normal flow in Odoo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use context to pass invoice relations to the new payment:

```
new_payment = self.env['account.payment'].\
    with_context(active_ids=ni.ids, active_model='account.move', active_id=ni.id)

np = new_payment.create({ ......
```

Note: `communication` field of payment model is a `char` field so you are assigning `account.move` object to a `char` field, which is wrong. You can for example, pass `name` of the invoice.

```
'communication': ni.name,
```